# Should I use pip3 or pip? Should I delete old packages and reinstall them in Virtual Environments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

I have been using python and now I am going to start to use python3 instead python(python2.7).

But so far when I use

```
pip install
```

I only used pip not pip3.

And I did not install python packages in virtual environments (which is a mistake I want to fix now)

My questions are

- Will there be any issues that I am using python3, but using pip to install the packages instead of pip3?
- If I am going to use python3 instead of python now, should I remove all  the old packages I installed using pip before, and use pip3 to reinstall the packages?
- AND My old python packages were not installed in virtual environments, should I remove all these old packages anyway, and start to reinstall the packages in virtual environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create virtual environment using `venv` module which is included in Python 3.

Here are the steps to create and install packages in virtual environment using Python 3.

Step 1: Create virtual environment:

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

Step 2: Activate virtual environment:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Step 3: Upgrade `pip`:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Check `pip` version:

```
pip --version
pip 19.1.1 from /home/.../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

Here we are seeing that, `pip` is using Python 3 inside the virtual environment. No need to use `pip3` in virtual environment.

Check installed packages inside the virtual environment:

```
pip freeze
pkg-resources==0.0.0
```

This new environment does not include any of the system wide installed packages. So, you do not need to uninstall the globally installed packages.

Rather than installing required packages globally for Python 3, create virtual environment and install them inside the environment.

**Reference:**

- [Python official documentation on creating virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments)